# Creating new image for given size containing cropped image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I am currently working on the below and am struggling to understand the best approach.
I've searched a lot but was not able to find answers that would match what I am trying to do

**The problem:**

1. Relocating an Object (e.g. Shoe) within the existing image (white background) to certain location (e.g. move up)
2. Inserting and positioning the Object (e.g. Shoe) at by the user specified location within a new background (still white) with by the user specified new height / width

[image]

**How far I got:**

I've managed identify the object within the picture using CV2, got the outer contours, added a little padding and cropped the object (see below). I am happy with cropping it that way as all my images have a one coloured background and I will keep the background in the same colour.

**Where I am stuck:**
My cropped Object and old image background / new background do not share the same shape, hence I am not able to overlay / concatenate / merge ...
Given both images are store as np arrays, I assume the answer will be to somehow place the Shoe crop np.array within the background np.array, however I have no clue how to do this.
Maybe there is an easier / different way to do this?

Would be very grateful to hear from anyone who can lead me into the right direction.

**Code**

```
#importing dependencies    
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

# Config 
path = '/Users/..../Shoes/'
img_list = os.listdir(path)
img_path = path + img_list[0]
#Outline
color = (0,255,0)
thickness = 3
padding = 10

# convert to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Identifying outer contours 
x_axis = []
y_axis = []
for i in range(len(contours)):
    for y in range (len(contours[i])):
        x_axis.append(contours[i][y][0][0])
        y_axis.append(contours[i][y][0][1])

min_x = min(x_axis) - padding
min_y = min(y_axis) - padding
max_x = max(x_axis) + padding
max_y = max(y_axis) + padding

# Defining start and endpoint of outline Rectangle based on identified outer corners + Padding 
start_point = (min_x, min_y) 
end_point = (max_x, max_y) 

image_outline = cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

plt.imshow(image_outline)
plt.show()

#Crop Image
crop_img = image[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x]
print(crop_img.shape)
plt.imshow(crop_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to take the cropped image of the shoe ( from your original image ) and place it in the center of a new image ( with the same background )?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got to the solution, this centers the image for any new given background height/width

Still interested in quicker / cleaner ways

```
#Define the new height and width you want to have  
new_height = 1200
new_width = 1200
#Check current hight and with of Cropped image 
crop_height = crop_img.shape[0]
crop_width = crop_img.shape[1]

#calculate how much you need add to the sides and top - basically halft of the remaining height / with ... currently not working correctly for odd numbers
add_sides = int((new_width - crop_width)/2)
add_top_and_btm = int((new_height - crop_height)/2)

# Adding background to the sides
bg_sides = np.zeros(shape=[crop_height, add_sides, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
bg_sides2 = 255 * np.ones(shape=[crop_height, add_sides, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
new_crop_img = np.insert(crop_img, [1], bg_sides2, axis=1)
new_crop_img = np.insert(new_crop_img, [-1], bg_sides2, axis=1)

# Then adding Background to top and bottom 
bg_top_and_btm = np.zeros(shape=[add_top_and_btm, new_width, 3], 
dtype=np.uint8)
bg_top_and_btm2 = 255 * np.ones(shape=[add_top_and_btm, new_width, 3], 
dtype=np.uint8)
new_crop_img = np.insert(new_crop_img, [1], bg_top_and_btm2, axis=0)
new_crop_img = np.insert(new_crop_img, [-1], bg_top_and_btm2, axis=0)

plt.imshow(new_crop_img)
```

[image]